# How can I delete documents from couchdb using filters?

Tags: couchdb

I'm searching a curl command to delete documents filtered with few conditions or other ways to delete specific documents. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in one query like you would do in SQL.

You have to query the documents with a filter (let's say a Mango Selector). Then, you need to update those documents with the field `"_deleted": true` to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

[Photon admin panel](https://github.com/ermouth/couch-photon) since v1.9.30 allows to select results of viewindex function and treats a selection as a list of documents. Having appropriate index you can select its parent docs and then delete them.